# How do I know what apps on my stackexchange account I have already authorized?

Tags: support, stackauth, stackapps

I'm developing an app using the stackexchange oauth, I want to revoke my permissions to this app for testing the overall process, but I can't find which apps I have authorized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look to the **apps** link on your [Profile page](https://stackapps.com/users/12568/agares) *.

<sup>* or follow [this](https://stackapps.com/users/apps/12568) link</sup>